# Quiz layout improvement

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm about to do a simple quiz.
I wan't to print all the questions out in one page, with a well formatted layout like:

Question 1
Answer 1
Answer 2

Question 2
Answer 1
Answer 2

I'm currently working on following code:

```
$get_qa = $mysqli->query("
SELECT
    a.question AS question,
    a.id AS qid,
    b.answer AS answer,
    b.qid AS aqid (related to: question id)
FROM rw_questions a
LEFT OUTER JOIN rw_qanswers b ON a.id = b.qid");

while($qa = $getqa->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $qa['question'].$qa['answer'];
}
```

This will result in a messy list. But how do i improve this like, what i wrote at the top?
Any help is cool!
I would guess i need to improve it with foreach or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually answered my question:
[PHP & MYSQL: using group by for categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977213/php-mysql-using-group-by-for-categories)

I'm shure DanFromGermany's solution worked, if i had the time to tweak it a littlebit :)

Answer (score 1):

Build 2 arrays, one of them 2-dimensional

Like:

```
questionId    question        answer
         1    sky has color?  blue
         1    sky has color?  red
         2    what is?        answer 1
         ....
```

save in an array like this:

```
$questions[1] = "sky has color?";
$answers[1][0] = "blue";
$answers[1][1] = "red";
$questions[2] = "what is?";
$answers[2][0] = "answer 1";
```

php:

```
$questions = array();
$answers = array();

// Take every row
while($qa = $getqa->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Add questions
    // $question[1] = "sky has color?";
    $question[$qa['qid']] = $qa['question'];

    // If no answers have been set yet, init an array
    if (!is_array($answers[$qa['qid']]) {
        $answers[$qa['qid']] = array();
    }

    // Add answers
    // $answers[1][] = "blue";
    // $answers[1][] = "red";
    $answers[$qa['qid']][] = $qa['answer'];
}
```

then loop it:

```
// Loop $questions array
foreach ($questions as $qid => $question) {
    echo "<p>Question: " . $quesion . "</p>";

    // Loop $answers[questionId] array
    foreach ($answers[$qid] as $answer) {
        echo $answer . "<br />";
    }
}
```

This answer can be improved but should work and give you a good kickstart.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer. However when i am trying your code nothing is being printed. It's a bit hard to bugtrace the code, when it's not in depth being explained :P Do you have an idea what might be wrong there? :)

Comment: Added explanation and comments

Comment: Hmm. Still seems that i can't get this code to work. Thank you very much for the comments, that helped a lot. It is still not printing anything out :/

Comment: what happens when you do this: `while($qa = $getqa->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($qa);
}`

Comment: If i try to print the $qa variable it returns an array with the questions, and only one answer for each question :)

Comment: Try to do a normal `JOIN` in your query, without `OUTER LEFT`, if it does not help, you can send me a pastebin with your table structure + some data and I will write a query+loop for you that works